# How Zigbee devices preserve battery being disconnected?

Tags: smart-home, zigbee

I have some Zigbee devices like movement sensors, wall switches etc. Some of them are rarely used and I started to think about how much battery they consume when disconnected because I don't want them to lose charge with no use. I'm interested if Zigbee devices get shut down or go into some power-saving mode when they stay disconnected for a long.

Having an answer I'll be able to decide if it's enough just to reset those devices and put them aside or if I would better eject their batteries to save a charge.

Comment: This probably depends a lot on the device and what you did with it. As long as it’s still connected to a network it will usually continue to try to ping the network for any traffic targeting it. If you disconnect it from the network, some devices will continuously attempt to find a network allowing them to join. Others will indeed go to a lower power sleep pattern and not do anything until they are put back in joining mode (usually after a reset, pressing a button or the like). If you really want to be sure they don’t use power take the batteries out.

Comment: What @jcaron said. Also - Zigbee is a radio protocol. It's not a brand or manufacturer. The main thing you can say about Zigbee devices is they all talk Zigbee (and some, frankly, barely do that). You can't generalize about their behavior beyond that.